# Finding Midpoint of Even or Odd Set of Numbers - Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am having a problem running the following code:

```
Num = '123456'

if (Num % 2 == 0):
    MidpointEven = Num[len(Num)/2 - 1]
    print MidpointEven

else:
   MidpointOdd = Num[len(Num)/2]
   print MidpointOdd
```

The message that I get when running the program says " if (Num % 2 == 0):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Would you please advise me how to fix this error?

Comment: `len(Num)` is the number you want

Comment: I think the duplicate is not set to the proper one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `%` with string, it tries to format the string , but you do not have any format specifiers inside the string, causing the issue. I think you meant to do -

```
if len(Num) % 2 == 0:
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.